# Instantiating a class within a subclass and accessing its instance within another subclass

Tags: ruby

I have a class:

```
class Player
  def initialize(name, npc=true)
    @name = name
    @npc  = npc
  end
end
```

and also a parent class and some subclasses:

```
class Scene
end

class Intro < Scene
  joe = Player.new("Joe", false)
end

class NeighboursHouse < Scene
end
```

I create a new instance of `Player` within `Intro`, and I need to access that instance in `NeighboursHouse` too. Is there a way to do this without repeating in every subclass?

Just to clarify, I want to be able to create new Player instances within each Scene and access them in other scenes. They may be created at random based on differing outcomes so I won't necessarily be able to create them in the parent class.

Comment: Not clear. What are the relations among those subclasses?

Comment: I'm essentially working on a console based adventure game, so you move from scene to scene, and each subclass is-a scene, and as the game expands I would like for subclasses to be able to inherit from Scene.

Comment: Why does `joe` have to be created in `Intro`? Can't it be created in `Scene`?

Comment: I think the question is confusing everybody because nobody understands what the purpose of joe is. Maybe you can edit so it will be more obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a program designing problem. If I were you, I would rather let the class `Player` to manage the players, and let the `Scene`s "invite" the players whenever it needs one.

```
class Player
  @players = {}

  def self.[](name, npc=true)
    @players[name] ||= new(name, npc)
  end

  def initialize(name, npc=true)
    @name = name
    @npc  = npc
  end
end
```

And when you need a player, for example in `Intro`:

```
class Intro < Scene
  joe = Player["Joe", false]
end
```

In this way, you don't need to worry about creating duplicated players.

The only setback is that there can't be 2 players with the same name but one is npc and the other is not.

Comment: Make it `@players[[name, npc]]` and the setback is solved.

Comment: Thank you - this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, but I guess you can just create the instance in `Scene`, and refer to it from the subclasses.

```
class Scene
  @@joe = Player.new("Joe", false)
end

class Intro < Scene
  @@joe # => refers to the object
end

class NeighboursHouse < Scene
  @@joe # => refers to the same object
end
```

Answer (score -1):

If the question is how to get some code snippet to run every time a class is inherited (but only once per inheritance), then you are looking for `inherited`:

```
class Scene
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    super
    joe = Player.new("Joe", false)
  end
end
```

Comment: Assigning local variable `joe` makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: I agree, but the question is not about the player instance but if there is a way to get some code to run in the context of every inherited class. The answer is yes.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect that `joe` will be instantiated once, which is what I assume you were wondering about.

Comment: Aetherus' answer was the best solution for my needs (sorry I tried to explain clearly, but the jargon is still quite new!!) but I think I can use this elsewhere in my project for more defined circumstances - thank you!

Comment: @JoeStephens please upvote, somebody has already punished me for my answer :(

Comment: @Ronna I have. I don't have 15 reputation points yet, but once I do then the vote will count.